# Objective c == strings and isEqualToString method not finding match

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to find out if a 1 letter string appears in the first 2 letters of a different string. I have tried to compare the strings with == as well as the isEqualToString NSString method.
Does anyone have any idea why my code is not able to find a match. It always just returns 0.
I am wanting the methods to be returning 2 as the letter b is in the second letter location in the word (first parameter) and should match the letter (second parameter)

main method:

```
    Finder *f = [[Finder alloc]init];

    int position = [f findLetterLocation : @"abc" : @"b"];
    NSLog(@"using == %d", position);

    int position2 = [f findLetterLocation2 : @"abc" : @"b"];
    NSLog(@"using isEqualToString %d", position);
```

Finder.m

```
-(int)findLetterLocation: (NSString*)word : (NSString*)letter{
NSRange MyOneRange = {1, 1};
NSRange MyTwoRange = {2, 1};

NSString *firstCharacter = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *secondCharacter = [[NSString alloc] init];

firstCharacter = [word substringWithRange:MyOneRange];
secondCharacter = [word substringWithRange:MyTwoRange];

if(firstCharacter == letter){
    return 1;
}
if(firstCharacter == letter){
    return 2;
}
return 0;
}
```

findLetterLocation2 is exactly the same as the method above but only replaces the if statements with the ones below:

```
if([firstCharacter isEqualToString: letter]){
    return 1;
}
if([firstCharacter isEqualToString:  letter]){
    return 2;
}
```

The output is

```
2012-12-29 18:14:51.253 test[83101:303] using == 0
2012-12-29 18:14:51.255 test[83101:303] using isEqualToString 0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining a method `-[Finder findLetterLocation::]`.  You want this method to return the 1-indexed location in the first argument ("word") of the second argument ("letter") if it is the first or second letter and otherwise return `0`.  This implementation will do the trick:

```
-(int)findLetterLocation: (NSString*)word : (NSString*)letter
{
    int res = 0;
    if (word && 
        letter &&
        [letter length] == 1) {
        NSRange range = [word rangeOfString:letter];
        if (range.location < 2) {
            res = range.location + 1;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

---

This method name is unconventional.  A better method name would be

```
- (int)locationInString:(NSString *)string ofLetter:(NSString *)letter
```

A still better method name would be

```
- (int)pfx_oneIndexedLocationInFirstTwoCharactersOfString:(NSString *)string ofCharacter:(NSString *)letter
```

where `pfx` is replaced with your project's prefix.

---

This method's return type should not be `int`.  Instead it should be either `NSUInteger` or `NSInteger`, probably `NSUInteger` since the result will always be `0`, `1` or `2`.

```
- (NSUInteger)pfx_oneIndexedLocationInFirstTwoCharactersOfString:(NSString *)string ofCharacter:(NSString *)letter
```

---

This method should probably be in a category on `NSString` rather than in a stand-alone class `Finder`:

```
@interface NSString (Locating)

- (NSUInteger)pfx_oneIndexedLocationInFirstTwoCharactersOfCharacter:(NSString *)character

@end

@implementation NSString (Locating)

- (NSUInteger)pfx_oneIndexedLocationInFirstTwoCharactersOfCharacter:(NSString *)character
{
    int res = 0;
    if (character &&
        [character length] == 1) {
        NSRange range = [word rangeOfString:letter];
        if (range.location < 2) {
            res = range.location + 1;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

NSRange uses location as index 0. the characters you are getting are character 2 and character 3.

Also. I believe that NSString will only match with == if you use the same object.

To match strings use -[NSString isEqualToString:]

Hope that helps

You can test with

```
NSLog(@"First Character = %@", firstCharacter);
```